Identify this 90s-00s movie, where a guy is chased by a hitman
I'm looking for a snatch-like movie, where a guy, accidentally I think, killed the son of a mob boss and the boss sends a hitman for revenge.
In the end the hitman killed another guy and it was blamed on him and not in the "real" killer.
It was a movie in the style of snatch from 2000..ala crime comedy.
it was from the 90s or 00s... but not sure...
it was colored, probably american production, real life, no animation....

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

it sounds like it MIGHT be Ghost Dog: Way of the Samurai. It ended with him (ghostdog) letting himself be blamed for the assassinations to save his mafia "shogun".
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165798/videoplayer/vi3735617817?ref_=tt_pv_vi_aiv_1

What does "snatch-like" mean?

Sounds like Run from 1991 starring Patrick Dempsey. A college kid accidentally kills the son of a mob boss and then goes on the run. It has plenty of comedy elements to it, was an American production, and in color.
